# Securing javax.websocket API in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I created a websocket communication between my Front-End which is coded in `Vuejs` and my Back-end which is coded in `Spring Boot`. Any user would authenticate in the first place ( the authentication is done without the websockets and a JWT token is passed to the user ) .And then a candidate would start a test (it's an e-learning platform) and the questions would be passed through a full-duplex flow with websockets. The client which is the `Vuejs` instance would submit the answer and the back-end would give him the next question. Well, the entire flow works. But I couldn't figure out how to secure the websockets. I haven't used neither `STOMP` neither `SockJS` for this and actually I haven't found a single ressource about this.
What I'd like to do is make a check on the user's role before giving him the permission to connect onto the websocket.
If the user has the privileges to access then the connection is successful
else it's a forbidden error (403).
Here is my code, I've used the `Spring Boot websocket-starter` annotations `@ÒnOpen`,`@OnMessage`, `@OnClose` and `@OnError`.
Those are some pieces of Code that may help out in finding the solution :

**WebsocketConfiguration :**

```
@Configuration
public class WebsocketConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
    
}
```

**WebSocket.java(Contains the logic):**
I removed the logic so that it doesn't become too much code to read.

```
public class WebSocket {

private Session session;
@Autowired
QuestionRepository questionRepository;
private static CopyOnWriteArraySet<WebSocket> webSockets =new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
private static Map<String,Session> sessionPool = new HashMap<String,Session>();
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam(value="tentativeId")String tentativeId) {
}

@OnClose
public void onClose() {
    webSockets.remove(this);
    System. out. println ("[websocket message] disconnected, total:"+webSockets. size ());
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message,@PathParam(value="tentativeId") String tentativeId) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
    }
    

// This is a broadcast message.
public void sendAllMessage(String message) {
    for(WebSocket webSocket : webSockets) {
        System.out.println ("[websocket message] broadcast message:"+message);
        try {
            webSocket.session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// This is a single message
public void sendOneMessage(String tentativeId, String message) {
    Session session = sessionPool.get(tentativeId);
    if (session != null) {
        try {
            session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried spring security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-authentication

Comment: those were designed for stomp endpoints, in my case i'm using java Websocket API. I tried using Stomp but it interferes with the WebSecurityConfig and I couldn't find a way to fix it tbh

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ? with tests inside